# Xcode fails to build the project due to Bus error: 10

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to "archive" an existing project after Xcode upgrade to 10.2 (10E125) and it continuously fails.

But it works perfect when I'm building and running the project on simulator / device and even when target device is "Generic iOS Device".

Looks like the issue is related only to "Archive" function.
Complete error text is the following:

> Command failed due to signal: Bus error: 10

and no extra details unfortunately..

I've already tried Cleaning the project, removing "Derived Data", restarting my Mac but nothing helps.

Could you please suggest if that's can be fixed or any workaround exist?

Answer (score 0):

Still not able to find a 100% valid solution to that but notice that continuously trying to Archive sometimes succeeds without any code / configuration changes **(randomly)**

I would say each ~10th Archive attempt succeeds.
That's my temporary workaround for now - Archive until Archived...